# Nilpotent elements of $\Bbb Z[x]/I$ where $I$ is a set of polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ideals, nilpotence

We are asked to find out nilpotent  elements of $\Bbb Z[X]/I$ where $I$ is the set of polynomials $f$ such that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your efforts.